# Is there any programmable parallel programming environment\framework for C# developers?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

So what I want is simple - control over processes that are ran on different connected (at least via ethernet) group\grid\cluster of PCs... something like "Parallel C#" but in form of array of .net libs and programs.

Is there any programmable parallel programming environment\framework for C# developers?

Comment: This sounds more like distributed or grid computing than parallel computing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [dryadlinq](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/dryadlinq/)

Comment: I believe that the software will allow Win7 on its nodes, but the cluster requires at least one server machine (2k3 or higher).

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of problem that Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) was created for.

There's also a grid computing framework called [alchemi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/alchemi/files/) that might be useful.